# Laravel Enum - Class "App\Enums\IssueStatus" not found

Tags: laravel, enums

I am trying to use Enum in my laravel project, but I am facing this issue. It cannot find the class IssueStatus in my Model, I would like to use it in my sql.. how can I use it in laravel?

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Enums\IssueStatus;

class Issue extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'issues';
    protected $fillable = [
        'shop_id', 
        'title', 
        'description',
        'status'
    ];

    /**
     * Get all issue without "resolved".
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
     */
    public static function scopeNotResolved()
    {
        return self::join('shop', 'issues.shop_id', '=', 'shop.id')
            ->select('issues.*', 'shop.shop_name')
            ->where('issues.status', '!=', IssueStatus::RESOLVED)
            ->orderBy('issues.status', 'asc')->get();
    }
}
```

Also, my enum class

```
<?
namespace App\Enums;

/**
 * Enum class representing the issue status
 *
 * @package App\Enums
 */
enum IssueStatus: int
{
    case NEW = 0;
    case IN_PROGRESS = 1;
    case ON_HOLD = 2;
    case RESOLVED = 3;        
}
```

Also, there is a message from phpstan

```
 Line   Models/Issue.php
 ------ ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  30     Access to constant RESOLVED on an unknown class App\Enums\IssueStatus.
          Learn more at https://phpstan.org/user-guide/discovering-symbols
 ------ ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: have you added the enums autoloading in composer.json file?

Comment: @OMiShah no need to add it into autoloading, it's already resolved.

Comment: As @PsyLogic say, no need to. But of course i try it, and got the same result :(

Comment: I am running on PHP 8.1

Comment: The same thing when u use tinker ? can u access Status from tinker ?

Comment: What do you mean by "tinker" ? @PsyLogic

Comment: `php artisan tinker` (cli)  and type `> App\Enums\IssueStatus::RESOLVED`

Comment: PHP 8.1.24 — cli Also in tinker i´ve got "Error  Class "App\Enum\IssueStatus" not found." @PsyLogic

Comment: @DanRais `App\Enums` not `App\Enum`, is your Folder Enums or Enum ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255681/discussion-between-dan-rais-and-psylogic).

Comment: try to replace '<?' with '<?php' in enum file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after testing .. You have to try using.

`<?php` instead of `<?`

```php
<?php
namespace App\Enums;
....
```

That will resolve your issue